# Convert text to datetime in matillion ETL tool

Tags: types, amazon-redshift, matillion

I have one filed Assessment_date with value as "2020-11-06T13:12:42Z" from source. I am reading as text into stage table.

Now I want to load into next table which is having dataype as datetime for this field.

In matillion how should I convert data from text to datetime datatype to load data into next table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the input table into a calculator component, create a new calculation.  If the input column name is 'DateTimeText', the calculation is: to_timestamp("DateTimeText")
[image]

[image]